# How to stop objects sticking out from the sides

Tags: objects, edges

Is there anyway to clean up the edges so it's just one smooth face instead of these things poking out without having to resize everything?

[image]

Comment: So you want to delete these parts?

Comment: Yes the parts sticking out from the sides

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

One way to fix this:

- Select your mesh
- Switch to Edit Mode
- Select all
- Press <kbd>P</kbd> then choose 'By loose parts'. This will divide the mesh by loose parts.
- Switch to Object mode.
- Select the objects (parts of mesh) which you want then delete them.
- Select all remaining mesh parts using <kbd>A</kbd>
- Join them to be one mesh using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>